# deploying YouTrack6 on OpenShift

Tags: openshift, youtrack

Some time ago, I've deployed a YouTrack5 instance on OpenShift, using [this excellent tutorial](http://toub.es/2013/07/15/youtrack-openshift-quick-and-simple). It works fine and smoothly.

Now, I want to install YouTrack6. Unfortunately, the same method can't be used for it, as since version 6 YouTrack .war file is [no longer available](http://forum.jetbrains.com/thread/YouTrack-1803).

So, I've tried to deploy YouTrack6 jar via a DIY cart, which should be ok, as the jar can be run standalone.

This is the command line that I've provided in the 
`.openshift/action_hooks/start` script:

`nohup /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0/bin/java -Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=250m -Djetty.home=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR -Duser.home=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR -Ddatabase.location=${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}teamsysdata -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}youtrack-6.0.12463.jar ${OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP}:${OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT} &`

Indeed, it works, the application is deployed and started - **BUT**: it is very unstable, looks like it crashes and caused to restart after just every few actions.

From the logs, I couldn't understand where the problem lies, looks like on YouTrack's side everything's ok.

My question is - what can be the problem that causes this unstable behavior, and is there any way to work around it (maybe by changing the command line flags, etc.)?

Comment: What size gear did you deploy this on?  According to the system requirements, i doubt even a large gear would run this well: http://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/download/system_requirements.html

Comment: @corey112358: Thanks for the link! It's installed on a small gear, which should be ok with their minimum requirements ("at least 512M"). Anyway, I suppose that the instability that I experience is indeed related to insufficient resources. Maybe I'll try to play with the JVM flags or just give up...

Comment: Have you found a way to host 6.5 on openshift?

Comment: @MacDragon: Nope, just gave it up...